# How to get value of jsonObject value in android?

Tags: java, json

I am building an android application and I am new to json. I am fetching below josn formate -

```
{
    "contact"[
        {
            "key1": "hey1",
            "key2": [
                {
                    "key3": "hey2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using below code to fetch key1 value. Now problem I am facing is how to fetch key3 value -

```
jsonString = http.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET, null);
if (jsonString != null) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        // Getting JSON Array node
        questions = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
        for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
            temp_obj = questions.getJSONObject(i);
            key1Array.add(temp_obj.getString("key1").toString());
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please help me

Comment: Always assuming that the JSON is inmutable as you present it, a"key2" is an object like "key1" but it contains another array of objects, so parse another array inside your "questions" array iteration which iterates the array inside "key2".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Gson to parse your json data. Let try it:

**First** of all, you must modify your json like this:

```
{
    "contact":[
        {
            "key1": "hey1",
            "key2": [
                {
                    "key3": "hey2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Second** add Gson to your libs and sync build.gradle: download [here](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/files/google-gson-2.2.4-release.zip) extract it, and copy/past gson-2.2.4.gson to libs folder.

**Third** Create some class:

FullContents.java:

```
public class FullContents {
    private List<ObjectKey> contact;

    public List<ObjectKey> getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(List<ObjectKey> contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }
}
```

ObjectKey.java:

```
public class ObjectKey {
    private String key1;

    private List<ObjectKey3> key2;

    public List<ObjectKey3> getKey2() {
        return key2;
    }

    public void setKey2(List<ObjectKey3> key2) {
        this.key2 = key2;
    }

    public String getKey1(){
        return key1;
    }
    public void setKey1(String key1){
        this.key1 = key1;
    }
}
```

ObjectKey3.java:

```
public class ObjectKey3 {
    private String key3;
    public String getKey3(){
        return key3;
    }
    public void setKey3(String key3){
        this.key3 = key3;
    }
}
```

And **Finally**, get data from url:

```
 private class ParseByGson extends AsyncTask<String,Void,FullContents> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected FullContents doInBackground(String... params) {
        FullContents fullContents = null;
        try {
            URL url=new URL(params[0]);
            InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8");
            fullContents=new Gson().fromJson(reader,FullContents.class);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fullContents;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(FullContents results) {
        super.onPostExecute(results);
        ObjectKey objectKey = results.getContact().get(0);
        Log.e(">>",objectKey.getKey1()+"--");
    }
}
```

you can put below code to onCreate:

```
ParseByGson parseByGson = new ParseByGson();
parseByGson.execute(urlStringHere);
```

**Update**: Explain

[image]

Comment: Thanks @vandaics you explain very well

Answer (score 0):

**1st of all: your json appears to be not valid (missing ':' after "content");**

After reviewing thins:

You can use the named getters to retrieve many types of results (object, int, string, etc);

```
JSONObject contact = jsonObj.getJSONObject("contact"); // {"key1":"hey1","key2":[{"key3":"hey2"}]}
```

or

```
String key1 = jsonObj.getString("key1"); // hey1
```

To retrieve key3, you should use:

```
JSONObject contact = jsonObj.getJSONObject("contact");
JSONObject key2 = contact.getJSONObject("key2");
String key3 = key2.getString("key3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the following code to what you are coding

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
   temp_obj = questions.getJSONObject(i);

   key1Array.add(temp_obj.getString("key1"));

   JSONObject temp_objKey2 = temp_obj.getJSONObject("key2");

   Key2Object key2Object = new Key2Object();

   key2Object.add(temp_objKey2.getString("key3"));

   key1Array.add(key2Object);

}
```

Comment: It's showing error in second last line - Cannot resolve method 'add(java.lang.String)'

Comment: The class `Key2Object` is only an example because you didn't give us the whole code. So you must adapt it. The `key2Object` can be the same type of `key1Array`